# Class which converts one type to another using registered lambda

Tags: c#, lambda

I want to make a class `TypeConverter`. This class should do:

1) It should allows to register conversion for specified type (int to string in my exmaple).

```
myClass.RegisterType<int> ((myIntValue) => (myIntValue + 1).ToString());
```

2)  Also there should be a method to easy converion:

```
string x = (string) myClass.Convert (5); // should return string "6"
```

In my not working implementation i Used: `Dictionary <Type, Func<object>> map;` to store my converters. And register function looked like this:

```
   public void Register<TIn, TOut> (Converter<TIn, TOut> converter)
   {
        map.Add (typeof (TIn), () => converter);
   }
```

And now I have problem to write a method for convering object

```
public object Convert (object o)
{
    // ... i can receive method from dictionary but i cannot execute it
    // because it is object, so  var converter = map[o.GetType] ();
   //  return converter (o); // will not work because i need to cast it
   //  but it is generic :/
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a similar learning curve in how to use a generic class in a non generic way which I couldn't figure out until I made a simple click: use an interface. So if you want to use your generic convertor in a non generic way, define a non generic interface and implement it. You loose any type safety unless you implement check to handle that.

So in your case, define a non-generic interface.

```
private interface IConvertor {
    object Convert(object obj);
}
```

Implement it in a generic convertor class that wraps a lambda.

```
private class Convertor<TIn, TOut> : IConvertor {
    public Convertor(Func<TIn, TOut> conversion) {
        _conversion = conversion;
    }
    private readonly Func<TIn, TOut> _conversion;
    object IConvertor.Convert(object obj) {
        if (obj is TIn) {
            return _conversion((TIn)obj);
        }
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Now store instances of that class in your `TypeConvertor` class.

```
public class TypeConvertor {
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, IConvertor> _convertors =
        new Dictionary<Type, IConvertor>();

    public void Register<TIn, TOut>(Func<TIn, TOut> conversion) {
        _convertors.Add(typeof(TIn), new Convertor<TIn, TOut>(conversion));
    }

    public object Convert(object obj) {
        if (obj == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");
        return _convertors[obj.GetType()].Convert(obj);
    }
}
```

Simple and easy to understand. Of course, you already did something like it by storing a `Func<object>` but unfortunately that doesn't work since it isn't an interface and the casting from `Func<TIn, TOut>` to `Func<object>` doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, I made exactly the same solution yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there's a good reason you want to build your own custom type converter, here is one way you could do this:

Usage:

```
TypeConverter converter = new TypeConverter();
converter.Register<int, string>((a) => a == 3 ? "three!" : a.ToString());
converter.Register<int, int>((a) => 3);

string resultAsString = converter.Convert<string>(3); // returns "three!"
int resultAsInt = converter.Convert<int>(4); // returns 3
```

Type conversion, invoking the delegate, and casting the result to the target type.

```
public class TypeConverter
{
    private Dictionary<KeyValuePair<Type, Type>, Delegate> _map = new Dictionary<KeyValuePair<Type, Type>, Delegate>();

    public void Register<TIn, TOut>(Converter<TIn, TOut> converter)
    {
        _map.Add(new KeyValuePair<Type,Type>(typeof(TIn),typeof(TOut)), converter);
    }

    public T Convert<T>(object o)
    {
        Type inputType = o.GetType();
        Delegate converter = null;
        KeyValuePair<Type, Type> mapKey = new KeyValuePair<Type, Type>(inputType, typeof(T));
        if (_map.TryGetValue(mapKey, out converter))
            return (T)converter.Method.Invoke(null, new object[] { o });

        throw new NotSupportedException(String.Format("No converter available for {0} to {1}", o.GetType().Name, typeof(T).Name));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one simple solution:

```
class TypeConverter
{
    private readonly IDictionary<Type, Delegate> map = new Dictionary<Type, Delegate>();

    public void Register<TInput, TOutput>(Converter<TInput, TOutput> converter)
    {
        if (converter == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("converter");

        this.map.Add(typeof(TInput), converter);
    }

    public TOutput Convert<TInput, TOutput>(TInput value)
    {
        return ((Converter<TInput, TOutput>)this.map[typeof(TInput)])(value);
    }

    public object Convert(object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("value");

        return this.map[value.GetType()].DynamicInvoke(value);
    }
}
```

And here is how to use it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var converter = new TypeConverter();

    converter.Register<int, string>(value => (value + 1).ToString());

    string x = converter.Convert<int, string>(5);

    object boxedInt = 5;

    string y = (string)converter.Convert(boxedInt);
}
```

Note that this solution uses [Delegate.DynamicInvoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.dynamicinvoke.aspx) which is rather slow, so if you are looking for a more performance-wise solution, you should go with already mentioned generic class which wraps [System.Converter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kt456a2y.aspx) delegate and implements interface which exposes weakly-typed conversion method.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static T ConvertTo<T>(object value)
    {
        try
        {
            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return (T)(typeof(T).IsValueType ? Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T)) : null);
        }

    }
```

You can use this method. Here is example how to use it:

```
   string test = "5";
   decimal d = ConvertTo<decimal>(test);
```